# What kind of issue may request a "cascade persist operation" for a Doctrine entity?

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I have a **Like** entity with a **getDislike()** function in my *Symfony2-Doctrine2* project. Once I retrieve a Like entity and I call the getDislike() function in an echo, nothing is printed.

```
echo '<br />'. $like->getDislike(); //Nothing is printed (1, 0, true, false)
echo '<br />'. $like->getId(); // the entity id is printed
```

If I call the same function with the same entity in an if condition,

```
if($like->getDislike() == FALSE){ //throw an exception
....}
```

then the following error is returned:

```
A new entity was found through the relationship 'Acme\ArticleBundle\Entity\Article#likes' that
was not configured to cascade persist operations for entity: Acme\ArticleBundle\Entity  
\Like@00000000653f908100000000749fcbfe. Explicitly persist the new entity or configure cascading
persist operations on the relationship. If you cannot find out which entity causes the problem
implement 'Acme\ArticleBundle\Entity\Like#__toString()' to get a clue.
```

Why the preceding error happens! The Article entity is not mentioned in my code (of course there is a relationship many Like to one Article and vice versa in the doctrine scheme).

Any idea?
Upon request, I add the Like entity file:

```
namespace Acme\ArticleBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;


/**
 * Acme\ArticleBundle\Entity\Like
 *
 * @ORM\Table()
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class Like
{


/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Article")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="article_id", referencedColumnName="id")
 */
protected  $article;    


/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="boolean")
 */
protected  $dislike;      

//.... other fields

/**
 * Set dislike
 *
 * @param boolean $dislike
 */
public function setDislike($dislike)
{
    $this->dislike = $dislike;
}

/**
 * Get dislike
 *
 * @return boolean 
 */
public function getDislike()
{
    return $this->dislike;
}

//.... other methods
```

}

Here is the article Entity:

```
namespace Acme\ArticleBundle\Entity;

use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;


/**
 * Acme\ArticleBundle\Entity\Article
 *
 * 
 * @ORM\Table()
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="Acme\ArticleBundle\Repository\ArticleRepository")
 */
class Article
{

/**
 *
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Like", mappedBy="article")
 */
protected  $likes;    

//.... other fields


public function __construct() {
    ...
    $this->likes = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();
    ...   
}    


}
```

And here is the controller code:

```
 public function likeDislikeItemAction(){               
    if ($this->get('security.context')->isGranted('IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY')){
        $user = $this->get('security.context')->getToken()->getUser();

        $entityType = "AcmeArticleBundle:Article"; // This static for debugging
        $entityId = 1; // This static for debugging         

        $doctrine = $this->getDoctrine();

        $item = $doctrine
            ->getRepository($entityType)
            ->findOneById($entityId);
        if(is_object($item)){
           $itemlikes = $item->getLikes();
           $totvotes = sizeof($itemlikes);
           $numlikes = $this->getNumLikes($itemlikes);
           $numdislikes = $totvotes - $numlikes;


            $dislike_value = 'like'; // This static for debugging                
            if($dislike_value == 'like') $isDislike = FALSE;       
            else $isDislike = TRUE;

            $like =  $this->getLikeDislikeEntity($doctrine, $user, $entityType, $entityId);

            if(is_object($like)) { 
              $test = $like->getDislike();
              echo 'test val ' . $test;
            }
        }
       }
      return NULL;
     }

     private function getLikeDislikeEntity($doctrine, $user, $entityType, $entityId){
       if ($entityType == "AcmeArticleBundle:Article") {
        return $doctrine->getRepository("AcmeArticleBundle:Like")
                    ->findOneBy(array('author' => $user->getId(), 'article' =>$entityId));  
       }
       return null;
    }
```

Comment: Should I have to update the Article entity that has one-to-many relationship with the Like entities?

Comment: Could you post a piece of code where you create/fetch `$like` object? Also post your schema.

Comment: I think that the problem is related to boolean fields. When I call echo $like->getDislike(), I see that it prints "1" if the field is set to true, it prints nothing otherwise. Is that the problem? What return the getDislike() function if the field is defined as boolean?

Comment: It returns a boolean, but `echo` statement treats booleans somewhat stragne. `echo true; // = "1"` while `echo false; // = ""` (empty string).

Comment: Post a schema and the code that causes the exception. (I guess you'll just have to add `cascade={"persist"}` for article-likes relationship.

Comment: Ok! I posted both the Entity schemes and the code of the controller. Thanks

Comment: I found the error, but I don't understand the reason! Notwithstanding that `$like` entity is an object, and `$entity->getId()` returns the entity id,  `$entity->getDislike()` returns null! I don't undestand why!

Comment: `Like::dislike` is not annotated as **not** nullable (`nullable=false`) so in theory it could be null - check whether you store true/false in your database. Also you posted the code as I asked, but it's way too long, post [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) instead of that wall of text (no one is going to read such a long snippet).

Comment: Well, I changed the schema with a `nullable=false` on the _dislike_ field (but I know that it should be false as default value), however the error remains!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I've found the error. I interpreted the error message ("*A new entity was found through the relationship 'Acme\ArticleBundle\Entity\Article#likes'*") and so I put the code:

```
$itemlikes = $item->getLikes();
```

after the code that retrieves the Like entity, i.e.:

```
$like =  $this->getLikeDislikeEntity($doctrine, $user, $entityType, $entityId);
```

Then, the error disappeared!
Maybe, the problem is that I'm opening two copy of the same row in the DB (one from the list obtained with `getLikes()` and another with the function to get the specific Like instance, i.e. `getLikeDislikeEntity`). I have to try `getReference()` from `EntityManager` to see if it doesn't provide the same error!